# I have had to do it/I had to do it

Tags: tense

As far as I know this is wrong:

**I have had to remind him about it every day for the last two weeks.**

It is wrong if I haven't done it. What other ways are there to express this idea?

> 1 I should have reminded him about it every day for the last two
> weeks.
>
> 2 I have needed to remind him about it every day for the last two
> weeks. ( but I haven't)
>
> 3 I had to remind him about it every day for the last two weeks. (but
> I didn't)

Comment: The sentence is perfectly natural, but means that you reminded him every day because he always forgot.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence itself is not grammatically wrong. However, you are right and it's not accurate for the situation you describe. Only option 1 of your examples is correct for your case:

> I should have reminded him about it every day for the last two weeks.

2 and 3 imply that you did remind him.

You can also say

> I would have had to remind him...

> I would have needed to remind him...

> He would have needed to be reminded...

Comment: I am surprised to have heard that 2 is wrong.

Comment: That's my mistake. I misread the sentence.